# Google Sheets - Incorrect result

Tags: google-sheets

I am confused with a Google Sheet I created.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0osuq_WFztRxNGcxXBhG5Hi6LSrHj8A5RCEwMnQZUs/edit?usp=sharing

These are bike times taken to complete 90 kms. These are split into 5kms chunks.
The interesting thing is that I input the time for each 5km chunk and calculate the speed in km/h from it. Then I calculate the total time taken using sum and the average speed using average. However this is incorrect. For Zell-am-See 2017 I get an average speed of 31km/h when the it should be around 28 km/h.

I can't seem to find the error. Initially I thought it was due to rounding but even if I change the data format to scientific nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an incorrect assumption about the mathematics. You cannot average the averages (you need total distance over total time) because the lower rates impact the average more than the higher rates because they happen for longer times. You might want to Google "harmonic mean" for more.
For example, suppose you go 120 km at 40 km/h, and then ride back at 30 km/h. You have traveled 240 km in 7 hours. Your average rate is under 35 km/h.

EDIT: Total distance over total time is the way to go. But if you want to satisfy yourself that it is the harmonic mean you want, add a column F to the right of your speeds, and in F3 say `=1/E3`, and drag that on down through F20. In F21 say `=1/AVERAGE(F3:F20)`, and behold you have the harmonic mean, which is the desired answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course, after you explained it makes total sense. I am however at awe that I didn't see that when I looked at the problem.